# Using Workspace.PendAdd in IIS doesn't work

Tags: tfs

I'm trying the WorkSpace.PendAdd method under Microsoft.Teamfoundation.Client namespace to add the local folder to TFS, it works normally when i debug with VS2010, but it doesn't work if it's published to IIS. I also tried giving the full control to the folder, but still no effect. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't work if _what_ is published to IIS? What kind of application is this running in?

Comment: I provided a potential path for you to look at.  For future references, saying "it doesn't work" doesn't give much for us to go on, while publishing the entire error or exception does.  Also, please try not to include the tag in the title.  I removed (TFS) for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see what identity the web app is running under.  Does that ID have appropriate rights in TFS?  If you're hosting on a web server that is not also your TFS application tier, you could also be running into the two-hop limitation of passing identity.

When you're running in debug mode, it is probably picking up your credentials, and since your machine counts as hop zero, there's no problem passing them on to the TFS application tier.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution after checking the `versionControl` `NonFatalError` event.

Before the calling to `workspace.PendAdd`, just call:

```
Workstation.Current.EnsureUpdateWorkspaceInfoCache(
                        _versionControl,
                        _versionControl.AuthenticatedUser);
```

(for some reason it's the only way the specific file folder path will be mapped when running in IIS)